# How can verify that a field with HTML extructura of my database have a correct structure?

Tags: html, laravel, drupal, migration

I'm doing a migration of a Drupal 7 site into a new project in Laravel to the tailored. Tables with text fields are in HTML format and sometimes this HTML is badly structured. I need a way to verify if the text have a correct structure. So, I ask:
How can I verify that a field with HTML data in my database have a correct structure?
I hope someone can help me, it's for my  thesis work, thank you very much!!

Comment: Small grammar adjustment and tag added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tidy php extension and repair_string method (function): to fix those strings:

http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php

But I'm not sure how reliable it is...